`numpy.astype` is slower than for loops for large arrays
I'm trying to use numpy to vectorize my code more and see performance benefits, but I was surprised to find that my code runs slower when using numpy.
I'm doing a very simple test to compare "native python" and "vectorization":
Setup:
from timeit import timeit

import numpy as np

TRIALS = 100

TIMESTAMPS = 10
CAMERAS = 5
HEIGHT = 240
WIDTH = 320
NUM_CUSTOMERS = 10

np.random.seed(0)

FRAMES = np.random.randint(0, NUM_CUSTOMERS, (TIMESTAMPS, CAMERAS, HEIGHT, WIDTH), dtype=np.uint8)

Native Python:
print("Native Python:")

def native_python():
    for t in range(TIMESTAMPS):
        for c in range(CAMERAS):
            (FRAMES[t, c] == 3).astype(np.uint8)
            (FRAMES[t, c] == 4).astype(np.uint8)
            (FRAMES[t, c] == 5).astype(np.uint8)

print(timeit(lambda: native_python(), number=1_000))

Vectorized Python:
print("Vectorized:")
def vectorized():
    (FRAMES == 3).astype(np.uint8)
    (FRAMES == 4).astype(np.uint8)
    (FRAMES == 5).astype(np.uint8)

print(timeit(lambda: vectorized(), number=1_000))

Here is information about my system:
$ uname
Linux
$ nproc
16

When I ran this on my computer, I was surprised to see Vectorization was 8 times slower:
Native Python:
0.9657893369439989
Vectorized:
8.072781160008162

I expected numpy to magically revert to native for loops even if this vectorized solution uses such giant loops.
Appreciate any help!

(FRAMES[t, c] == 3).astype(np.uint8) is still working on (240,320) shape arrays.  And it is iterating 50 times.  'vectorized' is working a whole array that is 50 times bigger. I have often observed that a small number of python loops on a complex task is faster than operating on the whole array at once.  Memory management complexity (paging, caching etc) with the larger arrays appears to slow things down.  Python level loops are not inherently bad.  There are tradeoffs.  Still an 8x slow down seems excessive, and may be worth exploring further.

'Vectorized' in numpy just means doing it in compiled code (c level loops).  There isn't any code in numpy to analyse arrays sizes, and revert to some sort of interpreted looping for optimal performance.

@hpaulj numpy not only converts to c level loops, but also indeed supports parallelism in threads in it's operations. And that's why it is faster.

@JohnnyCheesecutter No, it does not. Numpy is purely sequential. Numpy functions are only parallel when Numpy calls BLAS libraries which are the one parallelized, not directly Numpy itself.

My guess that this because not all operations in numpy supports multithreading. I found this list on the internet: https://superfastpython.com/multithreaded-numpy-functions/ From this list neither '==' or .astype are supported

@JohnnyCheesecutter The link seems correct overall and confirms this is BLAS functions which are parallelized (in fact, they are not always since it is dependent of the actual BLAS library linked but it is generally OpenBLAS on Linux which is multithreaded in most cases). LAPACK is not directly multithreaded (at least not the default Netlib standard implementation, but maybe if you use the MKL which support some LAPACK functions) but use BLAS primitive which are. Anyway, this is off-topic here since the OP do not use such functions.

Back to the question. My understanding is the same as Nathaniel's, if numpy does more efficient loops it's not clear why so called vectorized function is slower, it should be faster at least by some small amount.

On my rather small Windows laptop, the whole array vrsion is only about 25% slow

On mac pro M1 native is 0.7s and vectorized is 1.99s

You are actually comparing two vectorized implementations and the later is more expensive due to the memory hierarchy overheads (as pointed ou by @hpaulj in comments). The overhead of CPython loops is small in both cases.
More specifically, the former code operates on arrays of size 240*320 = 76800. which fits in the L2 cache on all mainstream CPUs  while the later operate on arrays of size 3_840_000 which does not fit in the L2 cache but the L3 on some CPU or only the RAM on others. The L3 cache is slower than the L2 and the RAM si much slower than the L3 cache. CPU caches closer to cores are much faster but also much smaller. Because of that, doing the computation chunk by chunk like you do in the first code is a good practice to improve temporal memory locality and thus performance.
One reason why temporal memory locality is improved here is because the internal allocator generally tends to recycle array (that is providing back the address of a newly deleted array of a similar size). This often happens on temporary arrays created by Numpy. Another reason is that temporary array are written and often directly read again and reading the array back is faster if the array is in a fast CPU cache. For example, FRAMES == 3 creates and fill a boolean array which is directly read back by the astype function.
On my machine with a i5-9600KF CPU, the L3 is large enough (9 MiB) to (mostly) hold the arrays so the difference in performance is not so huge. I expect this not to be the case on your machine.
However, note that .astype(np.uint8) is rather expensive here and not even needed in this case. Indeed, you can use .view(np.uint8). The former create a new array and convert items while the later just do a reinterpret cast of the item in memory without any copy. The later is only safe if you know exactly what you are doing. Here it is safe since the input (np.bool_) and output (np.uint8) types are of the same size (1 byte), both are unsigned and of a compatible kind (boolean versus integers). Once this modification is done, the code is much faster.
Here are performance results on my machine (with Cpython 3.8.1, Numpy 1.24.4 on Windows):
Initial implementation:
    - Native Python:  5.990550100000291
    - Vectorized:     9.843130900000233

Optimized implementation (using np.view):
    - Native Python:  0.9843445999999858
    - Vectorized:     2.8540657999997165

In the optimized version of the "Native Python" implementation, the big input array completely fit in the L3 and small temporary array do not impact is much so data is not evicted. In the second implementation data is more often evicted from the L3 cache because the temporary array is relatively big (the minimum space required is 3840000*2=7680000 bytes assuming the allocator and the cache optimal, but they are not and there is not enough space in my L3 cache for 3 times the array size, that is 3840000*3=11520000 bytes, hence a significantly higher execution time, not to mention the "Native Python" mostly operates in the L1 cache for temporary arrays).

Wow this answer is incredible. Thank you! I've seen your answers for many years and this is basically the first question I've asked on the site, so please accept my heartfelt thank you! :) Just curious, isn't numpy able to break down arrays automatically such that it can work on smaller subsets of the problem that fit in the L1 cache?

Thank you for your kind words! Numpy cannot really do that yet. At least, not without a huge modification of the API and maintainability issues. Indeed, what matters is the size of the input and output arrays for a given function. Splitting an array in chunks is useless unless it is an internal temporary array. The thing is the current API require the input and output array to be computed eagerly. A more efficient API could return abstract expressions that would be computed lazily so operation of multiple functions can be merged efficiently and care bout cache effects.

However doing that is rather complex, tends to make profiling more difficult (since operations are not done when the user call the function but when the output is read/needed) and makes the implementation much harder to maintain too. AFAIK, modules like CuPy (a Numpy-like module for Nvidia GPUs) can do such a thing in simple cases. I think Dask can do it too (AFAIK Numpy is used as a backend for Dask and Dask arrays are a grid of Numpy arrays).

Note that just as close CPU caches are faster than far/shared CPU caches and than then RAM, registers are significantly faster than CPU cache. This means doing 2 operations at once (without temporary arrays) is faster than doing the first operation, then write the result in a temporary array and then read it again for the second operation. This is especially true in Numpy since each function call has a pretty big overhead for small arrays fitting in the L1 cache. The thing is the Numpy API is pretty simple so it is often not possible to do many operations at once (at least not efficiently).

Thus, it is often better to use tools like Numba and Cython when you want high performance (so to write fast loops computing many things at once in each iteration without storing intermediate results in memory). Not to mention computing things chunk by chunk can be sometime tedious, difficult or just make the code significantly more complex. On the other hand, chunks are sometimes required for the computation to benefit from (wide) SIMD units of CPUs since complex loops tend not to be automatically optimized by compilers to use such SIMD units.
